# Handling multiple files in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file

I would like to upload multiple files to a web server.

This is the HTML (multiple is true):

```
<div class="file-chooser"><br>
    <input type="file" class="file-chooser__input" name="file_upload" id="file-chooser__input" multiple>
</div>
```

And the is the JS:

```
var files;
$('.file-chooser__input').on('change', function(event){
    files = event.target.files;
});

$('#reg_sw_button').on('click', function(event){
    event.stopPropagation(); // Stop stuff happening
    event.preventDefault(); // Totally stop stuff happening

    var data = new FormData();
    $.each(files, function(key, value)
    {
        data.append(key, value);
        console.log("File["+key+"]:");
        console.log(value);
    });

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8081/st_file',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false, 
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            if(typeof data.error === 'undefined')
            {
                console.log(data.success);
                console.log("First AJAX");
            }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
});
```

The problem I am struggling with is, the JS "on change" handler catches only the LAST selected file among the selected ones and sends it (fine) to the server. I also noticed that the "each" loop runs for only one time, for the last select file.

So how can I include more than one file in that "files" variable??

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: works fine for me using exactly your code (minus the ajax request, but you can see from the console it can read all the files if you select several): http://fiddle.jshell.net/en07ss28/2/

Comment: Yeah. It does work properly. I don't know why I thought I wasn't working. Anyway, thank you @ADyson :)